# send redirect and setting cookie, using laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, httpresponse

I have written this code, that sets a cookie in client's browser, and after that must redirect the client to 'home' route,

```
$response = new Response();
$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('language', $language));
$response->header('Location' , url('/home')) ;
return $response ;
```

the client receives these headers but  the client doesn't make request for the "home" route
[image]

how should I do both, setting the cookie and redirect the user?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using @Salar?

Comment: ali jan, I'm using version 5

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Why don't you do `return Redirect::to('home');`

Of course you can use chaining to do more things, both in L4 and L5.

L4: `return Redirect::to('home')->withCookie($cookie);`

L5: `return redirect('home')->withCookie($cookie);`

Comment: then how do I set the cookie?

Comment: You can use chaining. See the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses)

Answer (score 0):

just use the javascript method of redirecting
`<script>window.location = "home";`
and add it to your
$response =  new Response('')
like this
`$response = new Response('<script> window.location = "home";</script>'); $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('language', $language)); return $response;`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).