# set cookie in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I am trying to set few cookie variables and redirect to next route.

```
    $inputParams = [];

    $inputParams['show_match_skus'] = $this->request->input('show_match_skus');
    $inputParams['show_all'] = $this->request->input('show_all');
    $inputParams['prevent_dialog'] = $this->request->input('prevent_dialog');

    $inputParams = array_map(array($this, 'sanitizeInputParams'), $inputParams);
    $filterArr = array_filter($inputParams);

    if(count($filterArr) > 0) {
        if(array_key_exists('show_match_skus', $filterArr)) {
            $cookie_sku_match = Cookie::make('show_match_skus', true);                
        }
        if(array_key_exists('show_all', $filterArr)) {
            $cookie_all = Cookie::make('show_all', true);
        }
        if(array_key_exists('prevent_dialog', $filterArr)) {
            $cookie_prevent = Cookie::make('prevent_dialog', true);
        }

    }
    //dd(Cookie::get());
    //dd(Cookie::get('show_all'));
    return redirect()->route('list');
```

After creating cookies I need to redirect to `list` route.

But on checking in browser, I get none.

Also `Cookie::get()` displays only `XSRF-TOKEN` and `laravel_session`.

But `Cookie::get('show_all')` shows the cookie.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might be a duplicate. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870016/how-to-set-cookie-in-laravel-5-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870016/how-to-set-cookie-in-laravel-5-4)

Comment: You need to send it with your response:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550789/send-redirect-and-setting-cookie-using-laravel-5